# AWS Lambda https request yields "getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND" error

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, post, https, aws-lambda

I'm aware there's several answers to this sort of question on here already, but none of them seem to cover my scenario, in which I seemingly have followed all the rules necessary to carry out this POST request.

I have the following Node.js code in an **AWS Lambda function** that calls an API (the host and path are not real for security purposes).

```
const https = require('https');
let host = 'api-thing.place.com';
let path = '/api/info?appname=appname';

exports.handler = () => {
    let options = {
        'method': 'POST',
        'hostname': intHost,
        'path': intPath,
        'headers': {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json'
        }
    };
    
    let req = https.request(options, function(res) {
        let results = [];

        res.on("data", function(chunk) {
            console.log('data');
            results.push(chunk);
        });
    
        res.on("end", function() {
            let body = Buffer.concat(results).toString();
        });
    
        res.on("error", function(error) {
            console.error(error);
        });
    });
        
    req.write(JSON.stringify({"food":"apple","drink":"water"}));

    req.end();
};
```

This yields the error: "getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND api-thing.place.com."  What am I missing or doing wrong here?

Comment: Is your function configured to run in a VPC?

Comment: @MarkB not that I'm aware of.  How would that affect this code?

Comment: It would affect the network connections, which would cause errors like you are seeing, but if you aren't running in a VPC then that isn't the issue.

Comment: @MarkB in a hypothetical world in which I WERE running in a VPC, what would I do to resolve this?

Comment: It would require changes to the VPC subnet deployment settings for the Lambda function, and possibly adding a NAT gateway to the VPC and modifying the VPC route tables. None of those things are relevant if you are not running in a VPC. As long as you are not running in a VPC then the function should have Internet access by default.

Comment: I assume "api-thing.place.com" isn't the real domain name you are trying to access? Can you confirm the real domain name accessible from the Internet?

Comment: @MarkB You know, when you put it that way...the real domain is not accessible from the internet.  This is starting to make sense now.

Comment: How did you expect it to be accessible by the Lambda function then?

Comment: @MarkB. Ignorance?  Naivete?  I suppose since I can successfully make the same request via Postman, I believed I could do the same from Lambda.

Comment: How does it work from Postman if the domain doesn't exist on the Internet? Your question is really lacking in the critical details necessary for anyone to help you.

Answer (score 1):

If you followed this [tutorial](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/internet-access-lambda-function/) in creating the VPC and you are still facing issues, just edit DHCP options sets for the VPC that the lambda function runs in. You can use popular DNS like Google or Cloudflare.

The simplified steps in creating a VPC for lambda to access internet are:

1. Open the VPC wizard in the AWS Management Console.
2. Choose VPC with Public and Private Subnets. The new Public subnet and Private subnet, including their associated internet gateway and NAT gateway, appear in the Amazon VPC console.
3. Add AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole to Lambda's permission
4. Add created VPC to lambda and assign the private subnet to the lambda

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30342094)